# Scrolling in all apps on touchscreen in 14.04 desktop?

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen

I'm using a Samsung Ativ Tab 700t1c on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.

This is a hybrid tablet with a touchscreen, wacom digitizer and detachable keyboard dock, and a high dpi (HD in 11.6") display.

Is there any way to configure a universal scroll for the touchscreen?  The three and four finger gestures in Unity work as described here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch but they seem to assume that another driver (e.g. synaptics) is providing one and two finger gestures including scroll.

I've briefly tried touchegg and ginn without success.  Touchegg starts but doesn't seem to be able to capture any gestures.  Ginn fails with "error subscribing to gestures."

To make things worse, the touchpad isn't properly supported in linux so I can't use two-finger scroll when docked either.  Unfortunately, this renders the machine very hard to use as navigating to the scroll areas is very fiddly.

Thanks for your help!